# Bulk insert SQLite (100 - 1000 rows at at time) using db.execSQL or using using statement.bind ( i have 20000 records and 7 columns)

Tags: android, sqlite, bulkinsert, query-performance

Need to insert bulk data to SQLite ( 100 - 500 records at a time atleast ...having 7 columns , each row ll have 7 values)

Using statment.bind 
Plz suggest if something is wrong  and hw to implement using db.execSQL batch insert

```
    SQLiteDatabase db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    String  str = "INSERT INTO DBAdapter.KEY_BD1_DB_NAME(a, b, c, d, e, f,g) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,?)";
    SQLiteStatement statement = db.compileStatement(str);


    db.beginTransactionNonExclusive();

    try {


        for (int i=0;i<arraylist.length;i++)
        {

            statement.bindLong(1, id);
            statement.bindLong(2, alist[i]);
            statement.bindLong(3, blist[i]);
            statement.bindString(4, strTStamp[0]);
            statement.bindString(5, strTStamp[1]);
            statement.bindLong(6, j);
            statement.bindLong(7, tstamp);




            if (alist.size>100)
            {
                if(count==100)
                {
                    statement.executeInsert();
                    statement.clearBindings();
                    count=0;
                }
                else
                {
                    count++;
                }


            }



        }
        statement.executeInsert();
        statement.clearBindings();
        db.setTransactionSuccessful();


        Log.d("INSERT","Done");
        return true;
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Log.w("SqlErr", "At kkr : " + ex.toString());
        return false;
    }finally {
        db.endTransaction();
        db.close();
    }
```

Comment: is something wrong with your code? is it working? what's the question?  please be specific about what problem you're experiencing, what you've tried, etc

Comment: Above mentioned code will do the perfomance tuning for bulk insertion??...its taking time to insert data into db.....hv to insert atleast 100 rows at a time

Comment: how much time does it take? how much time is acceptable?

Comment: Your logic looks fine (Except for that `count` stuff). Prepare an insert statement, start a transaction, re-use that prepared statement every time in a loop with new value bindings until done, commit. There's not any magic better way - that *is* the better way already. Only thing I can suggest is maybe skipping the `clearBindings()` call and only binding the values that aren't going to change with each row once, instead of repeatedly doing it in the loop.

Comment: Around 80-90 secs

Comment: Oh, and look into `PRAGMA synchronous = OFF` and decide if the rewards outweigh the risks for your case.

Comment: db.beginTransaction();
Object[] values = new Object[numIterations];
StringBuilder valuesBuilder = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < numIterations; i++) {
    if (i != 0) {
        valuesBuilder.append(", ");
    }
    values[i] = mRandom.nextInt();
    valuesBuilder.append("(?)");
}

db.execSQL(
    "INSERT INTO inserts_1 (val) VALUES "+valuesBuilder.toString(), 
    values
);
db.setTransactionSuccessful();
db.endTransaction();

This is better or the one posted above??

Answer (score 0):

You can only insert one row at a time. So, stripping out the weird stuff from your code, and incorporating the bit I mentioned in a comment about only binding constant values once (Disclaimer: That would work in C; not 100% sure about java/android bindings), the standard approach to insert a bunch of data should look something like:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();

db.beginTransaction();
try {
    String  str = "INSERT INTO DBAdapter.KEY_BD1_DB_NAME(a, b, c, d, e, f,g) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,?)";
    SQLiteStatement statement = db.compileStatement(str);

    statement.bindLong(1, id);
    statement.bindString(4, strTStamp[0]);
    statement.bindString(5, strTStamp[1]);
    statement.bindLong(6, j);
    statement.bindLong(7, tstamp);

    for (int i=0;i<arraylist.length;i++) {
            statement.bindLong(2, alist[i]);
            statement.bindLong(3, blist[i]);
            statement.executeInsert();
    }

    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
    Log.d("INSERT","Done");
    return true;
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    Log.w("SqlErr", "At kkr : " + ex.toString());
    return false;
} finally {
    db.endTransaction();
    db.close();
}
```

Other stuff:

- [PRAGMA synchronous = OFF](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_synchronous) might be faster, but it comes with risks.
- A standard bulk insert trick is to drop any indexes on the table, insert data, and then re-create the indexes afterwards.
- If using foreign keys, temporarily disabling their enforcement during the bulk insert might speed things up too. Just remember to look for issues later with [PRAGMA foreign_key_check](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_foreign_key_check).

Comment: Thanks you so much Shawn

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to populate database on first use. But instead of doing that, it would be far both better, faster and simpler to just ship your app with ready to use database file in your app's `assets/` and then, on first use just use that DB for "seeding" instead. There are some helper libraries that helps with that: https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper